# How do I write this Loop?

Tags: python, selenium, loops, exception

I am trying to book an appointment on a website where I have to click the day I want the appointment. I want to create a loop where the bot reloads the page and tries to click on the same day again until it is available. Now my problem is that it says `"ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted"`. I already tried it with the "except NoSuchElementException" command. The Error is at "Termin_button". I am using Python.

```py
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

while True:
    try:
        wd.get("https://www.tuv.com/germany/de/termin-f%C3%BChrerschein/")
        accept_all_button = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="c-right"]/a[1]')
        accept_all_button.click()

        random_wait_time = random.randrange(2.0, 4.0)
        print(random_wait_time)
        time.sleep(random_wait_time)

        ort_button = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="input_hutvLocation"]')
        ort_button.click()

        random_wait_time = random.randrange(2.0, 4.0)
        print(random_wait_time)
        time.sleep(random_wait_time)

        weiter_button = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//* \
        [@id="main_content"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[5]/div[2]/a')
        weiter_button.click()

        random_wait_time = random.randrange(2.0, 4.0)
        print(random_wait_time)
        time.sleep(random_wait_time)

        weiter_button.click()

        random_wait_time = random.randrange(2.0, 4.0)
        print(random_wait_time)
        time.sleep(random_wait_time)

        datum_button = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//* \
        [@id="main_content"]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/label/span')
        datum_button.click()

        random_wait_time = random.randrange(2.0, 4.0)
        print(random_wait_time)
        time.sleep(random_wait_time)

        next_button = wd.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="ui-datepicker-div"]/div[1]/a[2]')
        next_button.click()

        random_wait_time = random.randrange(2.0, 4.0)
        print(random_wait_time)
        time.sleep(random_wait_time)

        random_wait_time = random.randrange(2.0, 4.0)
        print(random_wait_time)
        time.sleep(random_wait_time)

        termin_button = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ui-datepicker- \
        div"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/a')
        termin_button.click()
        break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("kein Termin")
        print("waiting for some time....")
        time.sleep(5)
```

[image]

The button is on every Day for example on the 21.02.2022 and if the Date ist available it is black like the 09.02.2022

Comment: Where is this button located in UI ? what are manual steps ?

Comment: I uploaded where the Button is located.

Comment: Also you have random \ in your xpaths.